# Is it possible to store image on user's browser

Tags: php, html, caching, local-storage, browser-cache

On my main page there is a big size image (~6 MB). It's kind of map.
I would like to store that image in user's browser even if they close browser or restart their PC, is it possible somehow?
That image is used in CSS file if it matter.
My hosting has small bandwidth, so I would like to store that image as long as I can on user's browser
Thanks for any tips.

Comment: If the user has not disabled caching, the web browser should save the image automatically. It will only check if you have made changes to the image.

Comment: You should probably think about optimising the image. 6mb is HUGE for a web-based image. There must be something that can be done to minimise it. And yes, the browser (if set to) will cache the image but that's nothing you can control

Comment: @Alex the server absolutely controls how the browsers caches.... Also 6MB is not huge in current days bandwidth. That is about 10-15 seconds on an average broadband connection...

Comment: 6mb is huge. Sure, a lot of people have broadband. But not everyone. Plus, optimising images is simple these days. I'd rather not have to wait more than a few seconds for the page to load, given the choice. Looking at Firefox, I can tell the browser not to cache an image. I can also tell the browser to limit the cache so it won't cache anything above x bytes. That's my control, not the servers

Comment: @S. Albano: Yea, I know browser will save the image after first load, but when I close browser and open again the image will be lost. Browser will need to download it again. I know it cuz it takes few seconds to load page after first run.

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately I can't do much to minimise it. If I won't find any way to store the image, I will have to slice it for pieces and load when needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few options for this, some more convoluted than others.

The most cross-browser way is to make sure you set your [cache headers to long cache times](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-cache-control.html), and keep the URL consistent (similar to @Petah's suggestion).

[Some browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) support the [HTML5 File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). You could use JavaScript to store images here if it's supported.

You could also use the [HTML5 AppCache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) (also with [limited support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=offline-apps)), but this means you have to be careful about how you structure your application - because the HTML page will be cached forever until the cache manifest changes.

You can also serialise your [image as a Data URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) ([fairly well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri)) and store that string locally somehow (localstorage, cookies), but since cookies have small size-limits, and you wouldn't want to store 6MB in the HTML 'cos the page would take forever to load, this is probably not a great option.

Comment: Wow, first time I hear about FileAPI and AppCache, thanks a lot! I hope to learn something new, even if I won't make it run.

Comment: Just by the way, all the client-side storage techniques will have  storage limits, and with a 6MB image, you're quite likely to hit them. Here's some information about how Chrome handles it: https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage#types

Answer (score 0):

You should look up caching best practices:

- https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx
- http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: I checked it while ago, I set in my .htaccess **max-age=1296000** (1 month), but after restarting my PC, browser lost the image. I checked HTTP Headers and there was 1296000 value, so it can't be problem with my web server

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the correct HTTP caching headers for that image. With them you will tell the browser (and any proxies in between) to hold on to that image for as long as possible. But that will not guarantee that once user has that image that he will have it forever. It could be deleted from the cache for numerous reasons (user clearing the cache, browser evicting it, ...).

Start with this [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=http%20cache%20headers). If you want something more specific, you will have to tell us what web server you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about bandwidth, **why not upload image to some image service** (there are number of those around the Internet), and include its url in your css?

There are some concerns with these (free) services you should keep an eye for:

- some image hosting services will block rendering of image (usually with image with text "not allowed to...") if
  included on other sites like in stylesheets, forums posts... so you have to choose the one that dosen't do that
- load time for image may vary dramatically if it is a free service, which is no big deal since once loaded in clients browsers, it will be cached
- service may be temporarily unavailable which may cause you inconvenience with your clients

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use these new HTML5 features which Robin posted above and if I will have some problems, then I will use your suggestion which is great btw.

Answer (score -3):

Try this.. Please change the href= to your image path and download= to the name of the file to be saved or you can leave it blank

```html
<a href="imagepath/image.jpg" download="myImage.jpg">Click here to
download image</a>
```

Comment: Like that you don't store it in the users browser but just give the user the opportunity to download the image and safe it to the file system. It will not being accessible in css after that.